# Is there any conflicts if I open a source code file with two different IDEs?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, phpstorm

I want to know if someone has experienced problems editing code on a development team with members using eclipse and others phpstorm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. Try to expose your issues, and ask if anyone already solve this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there should be no problem if team members use different IDEs. I use both on the same project in parallel, because each of the IDEs has its strengths and weaknesses.

One potential problem is that projects meta information is persisted in different forms between phpstorm and eclipse. Eclipse use a `.project` (and some other `.*` files depending on the project type) file in the root of the project directory. JetBrains products use a directory called '.idea`.

So, changes to the project settings made in phpstorm are not visible in eclipse and visa versa. That means changes in settings has to be communicated in other ways.

There is always the question if you should check in the `.project` and the `.idea` files. If everybody uses the same IDE I'd say yes. If team members use different IDEs it may not be clear what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the same project in two IDEs in the same time,
you should just remember to save files before switching to other IDE.

If any issues arise of differences, you should try how it works from command line.

For more general case see @Michael_Scharf answer